# SHA3-512 implementation in R?

Tags: r, sha

### Background

I'm trying to implement a GUI interface(shiny) for a back-end project that was previously implemented as a console application. The problem is that one of the modules uses the SHA3-512 to process a password and I'm unable to find an R package that implements it.
i tried using the [digest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/digest/digest.pdf) package but either I'm using it wrong, or its using sha1 and sha2 versions.
I also tried the [openssl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openssl/openssl.pdf) package to no avail.

### MRE

```
library(openssl)
sha512("qwertyui")
```

this is the result

```
[1] "043e34a704b33e08d927e54bd45800259e2280970f0dfd01bc72b15e0935445c25bb878989a43812ce27a31e42a03f8d1585e685d03dcc636a658e2b352f847e"
```

but i expected this to be the answer

```
[1] "8bd0591e81ccfc9d5a0c520b3357baa08ac9b3e6c1a42a37d8baffde3d1268c186d08391af0d1837ec969f1b33057f2ce050eecee35acfab093d4f5056617185"
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The [secretbase](https://cran.r-project.org/package=secretbase) package implements SHA-3 and SHAKE256 algorithms.

```r
secretbase::sha3("qwertyui", bits = 512)
#> [1] "8bd0591e81ccfc9d5a0c520b3357baa08ac9b3e6c1a42a37d8baffde3d1268c186d08391af0d1837ec969f1b33057f2ce050eecee35acfab093d4f5056617185"
```